# How to navigate between different nested stacks in React Navigation 5.x?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Parent Navigator

- Nested navigator 1

  - Screen A
  - Screen B
- Nested navigator 2

  - Screen C
  - Screen D

*How can I go **from Screen D to Screen B** in React Navigation **v5.0** ?*

I tried something similar to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#reset

but when I try to use `CommonActions.reset()`, it navigates to Screen C

I tried this;

```
    ...
    import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
    ...
    navigation.dispatch(
      CommonActions.reset({
        index: 1,
        routes: [
          { name: 'ScreenB' },
        ],
      })
    );
..
```

Comment: isn't index:1 referring to 2nd nested navigator (which includes C & D) ? Have you tried with `index:0` ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
navigation.navigate('Navigator1', { screen: 'ScreenB' });
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

Comment: I have a MessagesStack, And i want to navigate to screen in another stack "HomeStack" it works well but when I click to back button it returns me to that stack in the initial screen "HomeStack" not to the MessagesStack, Is there a way to handle it to back me to current stack "MessagesStack"?

Comment: For navigating between arbitrarily nested navigators, see: https://medium.com/swlh/react-native-nested-stack-navigation-bad56ea33820 "What If We Nest More?"

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
navigation.dispatch(
              CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [
                  {
                    name: 'Navigator 1',
                    state: {
                      routes: [
                        { name: 'Screen A' },
                        { name: 'Screen B' },
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              })
            );
```